# Ошибка при создании виртуальной машины VirtualBox Oracle

Tags: virtualbox

подскажите, пожалуйста. Установил VirtualBox на диск A (не основной). Создаю виртуальную машину и в строке Folder выбираю созданную мной папку на диске A:, чтобы вся информация в виртуальной машине была в этой папке,  но [image: введите сюда описание изображения]выходит ошибка: Can't create machine folder.

Изначально дефолтная папка почему-то на диске C, хотя установил на A. Поменял на A, но даже после изменения возникает такая же ошибка.

Что мне делать? Мне нужно создать виртуальную машину именно на диске A, потому что на C осталось немного места и его мне не хватит для выполнения задач. Помогите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен

Comment: A и B исторически были заняты под имена дисководов (сменных носителей). Я могу ошибаться, но возможно по этой причине виртуальная машина отказывается использовать эти имена.

Comment: Виртуальная машина занимает несколько килобайт - крайне маловероятно, что у вас не найдётся столько места. Наверное, вы хотите переместить виртуальный носитель - а его можно таскать куда угодно отдельно от виртуальной машины